# Is it possible to make an uploaded photo realtive in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, image-resizing

As in question is it possible to upload a photo and make it relative?
I am trying to upload an image to my GUI, but it is not relative, so when you maximalize window, then unfortunatelly there is a problem with its size.

I want to change the image size dynamically when the window is resizing

Some example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

HEIGHT, WIDTH = 640, 700
root = tk.Tk()
canvas0 = tk.Canvas(height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas0.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='black')
canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='#009900')
frame.place(relx=0.12, y=2, rely=0, relwidth=0.75, relheight=1)

column_1_img = Image.open('column.png')
column_1_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(column_1_img)
column_label_1 = tk.Label(canvas, image=column_1_img)
column_label_1.image = column_1_img
column_label_1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.2)

root.mainloop()
```

This code produces this output:
[Not fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCfGQ.png)
[Fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5tPi.png)

I want an image to automatically adjust to the label size, so do you have some ideas how?

Comment: Do you mean to change the image size dynamically when the window is resizing? BTW, better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Normally don't use `pack/place/grid` to put widgets into a canvas, use `.create_window(...)` instead.  For image, use `.create_image(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `<Configure>` to an event handler and use the PIL's `resize` method to resize the image.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def resize_image(event):
    column_label_1.resized = ImageTk.PhotoImage(column_1_img.resize((event.width, event.height), resample = Image.NEAREST))
    column_label_1['image'] = column_label_1.resized

HEIGHT, WIDTH = 640, 700
root = tk.Tk()
canvas0 = tk.Canvas(height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas0.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='black')
canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='#009900')
frame.place(relx=0.12, y=2, rely=0, relwidth=0.75, relheight=1)

column_1_img = Image.open(r'img_path')
column_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(column_1_img)

column_label_1 = tk.Label(canvas, image=column_img)
column_label_1.image = column_1_img
column_label_1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.2)
column_label_1.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)

root.mainloop()
```